# Can i filter Github PRs with logical Negation operator?

Tags: github

Tried a lot of searching in Github docs and also stackoverflow. Couldn't find a descent example to show how we can filter PRs with logical negation operator

Let's say I want to filter all the PRs which are `closed` and does not have `AutoDeploy` in title.

Tried the following but it does not work.

```bash
is:pr is:closed -in:title "AutoDeploy"
```

Answer (score 2):

From "[Understanding the search syntax](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/getting-started-with-searching-on-github/understanding-the-search-syntax#exclude-certain-results)", you can indeed prefix any search qualifier with a `-` to exclude all results that are matched by that qualifier.

However, that seems to apply to [repository search](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-for-repositories) only, *not* [issue and PR search](https://docs.github.com/en/search-github/searching-on-github/searching-issues-and-pull-requests), where the exclusion operator does nothing on the '`in`' qualifier.

You might need to list all pr, and then subtract the one with AutoDeploy (or grep -v to exclude them)

Using the GitHub CLI command [`gh pr list`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_pr_list) can help post-processing the results.

```
gh pr list --search "is:closed" | grep -v "AutoDeploy"
```

Comment: Thank you VonC. Wish there was an option to do it in the UI as in that case I can right away access the PR. Now I would again need to search for the same PR in the console.

Comment: @DockerNaughty I agree, an UI-integrated option would be easier. At least in the console, `gh` is a powerful CLI tool.